# How to reduce storage cost and also improve performance of a large table?

Tags: oracle, object, amazon-s3, nosql, rdbms

Overview:
We have a table in a database (Oracle) which is occupying pretty much 80% of the total space allocated to the database. This particular table stores data in a JSON blob format and contains trace information, mostly related to how the central engine works in the application.

Problem:
For certain clients, this trace information has grown at a rapid space to a point that this table now holds almost a terabyte of trace information. This has caused concerns related to high cost of storage as well as degraded query performance.

Question:
What are the best choices to tackle this scenario:

1. Use NoSQL to store the JSON blob data ? Not sure if addresses the cost though.
2. Store the JSON blob data in a cheaper object store and use Lucene/Elastic search etc for index and search? We do have an in house EMC object store appliance (ECS) that can communicate over S3 API. ECS is cheaper than SAN storage, however I am not sure about the performance though.
3. Use Oracle partitioning to store the JSOB Blob in a separate tablespace ? It was a suggested by a DBA sometimes ago, but I am not sure if it is going to address either the cost or performance aspect of the problem.
4. Any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Database compression may be the simplest way to quickly decrease the storage:

5. **LOB compression.**  If you have the Advanced Compression license, you can enable compression for the column.  This might be somewhat related to suggestion #3, except that changing the tablespace doesn't matter.  (Maybe the DBA was referring to a tablespace that was setup for compression.  But I don't think tablespace compression automatically compresses LOBs.)

   ```
   --These commands may take a long time to complete.
   alter table table_name modify column_name(a) (compress);
   alter table table_name move;
   ```
6. **UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_COMPRESS.**  If you don't have the Advanced Compression license, you could use the package `UTL_COMPRESS` to compress and decompress the data.  Although that might significantly change the way the table is used.